# Some jpeg images are not showing in IE8 and IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jpeg

I have a problem with some jpeg images which are showing without any problems in Mozilla, Chrome, IE10, IE7, but NOT in IE8 and IE9. The images are in RGB (and not in CMYK, some other users report it as a problem).

html:

```
<img class="lo" src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
```

css:

```
img.lo {
    display: inline-table;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The other images on page show normally also in IE8 and 9, but not this one. The other images in the same div show also.

Comment: Why do think it's a css problem ? Did you try opening them directly (i.e. with a link to the image) ?

Comment: any luck? also try to hardcode the width and height

Answer (score 0):

Make your you dont have this : width="" height"" IE takes this has width="0" and height="0"

Comment: I tried to define width and height, but it only leaves empty space and there is no image shown. I don't think it is an image problem, because it is shown in almost all browsers except IE8 and IE9

Comment: then it might be the inline-table